# Can we include VLC Player plugin in VB6 form

Tags: com, vb6, vlc

I want to include vlc mediaplayer plugin in vb6 form as a COM component ? I embedded it in .NET 2010. Is it possible to embedded in vb6

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can**. but you must use an old version of VLC Media Player. i'm using 0.8.6 version. You can download it from [here](http://www.filehippo.com/download_vlc_32/1958/).